# How to change view in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im wondering how i can change "views" with a button click in Visual Studio (asp.net)?

I have 2 `.aspx` files, one called `Default.aspx` and another one called `Library.aspx`. How can i make a button change the views to display the other aspx file?

I tried googling but didnt find anything useful. Any help here is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Classic old asp.net webforms? Are you under MVC? Different web framework could have different answers.

Comment: @Cleptus - Sorry, should've clarified - yeah, no MVC, usual asp.net webforms

Comment: I know a couple of ways, `Response.Redirect()` and `Server.Transfer()`. Note they do diffferent things, usually the former is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming default.aspx is in desing mode, then just drop a button from the toolbox onto the web page.

Say, like this:

[image]

Now, double click on the button, and we are jumped to code behind.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Library.aspx");
    }
```

So, we put for the code to jump to the web page Library.aspx

We get this then:

[image]

And now, when I click on that button, I am jumped to the web page called Library.aspx - we should see this (assuming the web page Library.aspx exists).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, ill check it out tomorrow!